# How to solve undefined labels in suiteCRM

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I am getting this error in **SuiteCRM**:

> "NetworkError: 404 Not Found -
>   /cache/jsLanguage/Home/en_us.js?v=9W_DRN8pphMvoAsvU564UA"

Please help me that how can I solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Admin > Repair and do a "Quick Repair & Rebuild".
Execute any changes shown at the bottom of the page.

If that doesn't work, go to Admin > Repair and do "Rebuild .htaccess file"
and afterward, Admin > Repair and do a "Quick Repair & Rebuild" again.

Answer (score 2):

Simply remove the cache folder from your instance files, and make a hard reload.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and the above answer did not work.

I found that the file/folder permissions were wrong, once these were updated `644/755` respectively everything started to work as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the commands you need to execute in the directory to fix this issue.

```
find -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

These 3 directories in SuiteCRM should be 777. or at least 775.

Cache
upload
custom

As lot of files re-generate while repair or cache build up, it needs to be full permission on those directories.

Answer (score 0):

the issue for me was super simple and none of these: my .htaccess file had an old directory listed so I did a control F, changed the directory name of where suitecrm should have been and currently is, and then saved it, and boom. all 'undefined' errors gone.  Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This is related to `RewriteBase` in `.htaccess`. Either you can manually update it by modifying `.htaccess` or execute `Rebuild .htaccess file`